# Bypass CAPTCHA in a website for web scraping in "Java"

Tags: web-scraping, captcha

I need to scrape details from a website which is having hidden Google CAPTCHA, help me in bypassing or solution is appreciated.

Comment: The purpose of a captcha is literally to prevent what you're trying to do. Have you considered hiring a large group of people solving all the captchas for you?

Comment: No , I didnt. Any solution to get rid off is most appreciated

Comment: Hi! Maybe you misunderstood part of my comment... Solving captchas by a machine is designed to be an extremely difficult problem and out of reach for most people. This is the only purpose for a captcha to exist at all.